# knitr, lyx, mac, Korean

Tags: r, macos, knitr, tex, lyx

Dear Friends in the knitr community with lyx and Apple Mac

Hello! I am using Apple Mac for Reproducible research of R. Currently, I enjoy knitr in lyx for writing some R scripts. The problem I have is related non-English characters, specially Korean in the knitr chunk.

When I type any Korean Character in a Chunk for typing file name or some extra explanations in #, the pdf output of the file does not print Korean properly. No matter of choosing or not choosing the option "eval=FALSE", R in lyx does not show Korean on the output. But, in the ordinary text part of the writing, Korean shows well. This problem seems to be Apple Mac specific, because another lyx environment in Linux (ubutu) makes the similar problem at al. Is it a lyx issue with MacTex or knitr one? Thank you in advance.

regards,

Jong-Hwa

Comment: This might be due to a pending LyX bug: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8537

Comment: Can you try starting LyX from the terminal and seeing if you still experience the issue?

Comment: Currently, I cannot run lyx from the terminal at Mac. A bash error, lyx command not found is printed out. I know where LyX is, /Applications/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/... Although, I can start LyX with clicking LyX icon.
There seems a path environment issue. Thank you - Jong-Hwa