# Export korean letters in knitr R

Tags: r, knitr

Is it possible to export documents that contain Korean letters using knitr?
I've tried it but it didn't work.

All Korean font changing like this, but all Korean letters work in R console.

[image]

Comment: Don't you think it might be useful to show what you have tried? Anyway, this might be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137529/knitr-lyx-mac-korean#comment33591097_22137529).

Comment: @Pascal I've add figure in my question, so it means this is bug?

Comment: This is not a bug, it's an encoding issue. Add a line to your knitr document that will display which encoding it's using (probably `native.enc`?).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and lazy solution is to use RStudio, which should handle the character encoding automatically. If you use other editors, or just call `knitr::knit()` manually, you should provide a proper value to the `encoding` argument. BTW, please post `library(knitr);sessionInfo()`.