# R Markdown Can't Knit File with Korean Character in the Filename

Tags: r, r-markdown

Apologies for any formatting errors, I don't use stack overflow a ton.

I've been trying to knit an R markdown file, but I keep getting the error:

```
Error: 'words ending with <U+D558><U+B2E4>.csv does not exist in current working directory
```

I've confirmed that the file is in my directory, but I'm guessing the problem lies in the fact that the filename has a Korean character in it. Is there a fix to this that doesn't require renaming the file?

Note that I can run the file perfectly fine in the console, and run the chunk in the markdown. The only problem is that I can't knit the file.

Reproduceable version below (runs fine, but runs into an error when trying to knit):

```
library(tidyverse)
test_data = tibble(col1 = 1)

write_csv(test_data, 'words ending with 테스트.csv')
test = read_csv('words ending with 테스트.csv')
```

Let me know if I've left out any important information.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525166/export-korean-letters-in-knitr-r

Comment: @nathanliang I've tried changing the encoding settings, but it doesn't seem to fix anything. I can also run the file perfectly fine in RStudio, so I think it must be a problem on RMarkdown/knit side.